# How to change Language in Radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Im creating a apps using Icenium(html,javascript and jquery mobile framework). one of the function of my apss is to change the language into french,english and german.
How can I do that? Without plug-in and with plugin ?

this is my Radio Button

[image]

Comment: We don't write code for you. Please have a go at doing it yourself, or at the very least think about it and present your ideas of how you might be able to do it.

Comment: very vague question, not a real question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript to detect an option select, i think onchange should work, and use it to load a dictionary or change to a translated version on the same page.